# Exporting every features of a layer as a own layer (using expressions) in QGIS 3.22

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, expression

I have a Shapefile with different features. Each feature is a Town in a specific region ( in the shape file). I want to automatically export each feature as a its own shape-file. So if the field "Town" of the following features are "Weitersweiler", "Welchweiler" and "Wendelsheim", I would like to export these as "Weitersweiler.shp", "Welchweiler.shp" and "Wendelsheim.shp".

A Python script or process modeling would be perfect as well.

Best regards, Magni

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A Python script or process modeling would be perfect as well.

This should work:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() # stores the currently active (selected) layer in the variable
crs = layer.sourceCrs() # stores the layers coordinate system in the variable
town_field = 'your_town_field_name' # optional storage of the field name

for feature in layer.getFeatures(): # classic for loop, iterating over each feature in the layer
    town = feature[town_field] # store the value of the currents feature attribute, alternative is to use feature['your_town_field_name']
    vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "temp name", "memory") # create a new virtual layer (in memory, see last argument)
    vl.setCrs(crs) # set the coordinate system from layer to the new layer
    pr = vl.dataProvider() # get the layers data provider (can't explain what it is exactly)
    pr.addFeature(feature) # add the feature to the layer via data provider
    vl.updateFeature(feature) # update the feature (similar to commit in data bases, if omitted, no changes are made)
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vl, "C:\\GIS\\towns\\" + town + ".shp", "utf-8", crs, "ESRI Shapefile") # writes the layer to disk (arg1 = layer, arg2 = destination, arg3=char-encoding, arg4=coordinate system, arg5=engine used)
```

Comment: This is brilliant and so it works. Thanks a lot. You would do me a huge favour if you went through what this code does line by line. That would be a great introduction to PyQgis. If not, you still helped me a lot!

Comment: I added comments to every line. I hope it's clear enough.
In case you work with larger datasets, QGIS might freeze and you'll need to use the TaskManager and QgsTask methods.

Answer (score 3):

The "Split vector layer" from the processing toolbox does exactly that :

> **Split vector layer**
>
> Splits input vector layer into multiple layers by specified unique ID field. Each of the > layers created in the output
> folder contains all features from the input layer with the same value
> for the specified attribute. The number of files generated is equal to
> the number of different values found for the specified attribute.

[image]